# How to get index of all the nodes in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I tried using:

```
TreeNode node = TreeView1.FindNode()
```

but it only finds root nodes. It is not able to find Child Nodes.

I want to get index of all the nodes and after that I want to use above code to find nodes by index and Check the Checkbox.

I tried using `foreach` to iterate through all the nodes, but I am not able to find child nodes and index.

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Yes. Added the missing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method allows you to traverse through a tree:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source
    , Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>(source);
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(next))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

Using this you can write:

```
var allNodes = new[]{root}.Traverse(node => node.Nodes);
```

You can then do whatever you want with the sequence of all of the nodes in the whole tree and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: What is <T> ? Is it TreeNode node?

Comment: @RKh It's a generic argument.  It can be anything you want it to be.  The method can traverse *any* tree, not just `TreeNode` instances.

Comment: So for a TreeView, what exactly I will pass? TreeView name or any Type?

Comment: @RKh I already showed you *exactly* how to call the method for your treeview right in my post.